# Proof of Hartogs' Lemma Q2

Tags: set-theory

I'm reading ["Sets, Models and Proofs" by I. Moerdijk and J. van Oosten](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ooste110/syllabi/setsproofs09.pdf) to have some basic understanding of set theory.

The last step in "Hartogs' Lemma" proof is a headache: "This is impossible however, since $[(Y_f ,\leq)]$ is an element of $P/\mathord{\cong}$ ". I don't understand where is the contradiction.

---

Update after Asaf's reply.

Below is my visualization of the concepts in the proof's last paragrpah.

$X$ is the original set;  $P=\{(L,\leq) \mid L\subset X, \leq \text{ well-orders } L\}$ ; the vertical axis in $P$ is what I imagine as the $\cong$-equivalent dimension; so the horizontal dimension is the $P/\cong$, with $\leq$ defined based on $\preceq$; $f$ is the bijection between $P/\cong$ and $Y_f\subset X$; $\leq_{Y_f}$ can be induced on $Y_f$ based on $\leq$ defined on $P/\cong$; $(Y_f, \leq)$ is an element in $P$; $[(Y_f, \leq)]$ is an element in $P/\cong$.

So far so good... where is the contradiction?

### [image: My visualization of the last paragraph in the proof]

Below is quoted from "Sets, Models and Proofs":

**Lemma 1.4.1 (Hartogs’ Lemma)** For every set $X$ there is a well-ordering
$(L_X,\leq)$ such that there is no injective function from $L_X$ to $X$.

**Proof.** Let $P$ be the set of all pairs $(L,\leq)$ where $L$ is a subset of $X$ and $\leq$
is a well-ordering on $L$. We shall denote the pair $(L,\leq)$ simply by $L$.

For two such $L$ and $M$, we write $L\preceq M$ if there is a (necessarily unique,
by Proposition 1.3.7) embedding of well-ordered sets: $L\rightarrow M$. Note:

- we have both $L\preceq M$ and $M\preceq L$, if and only if $L \cong M$;
- if $L \cong L′$ and $M\cong M′$, then $L\preceq M$ if and only if $L′\preceq M′$.

We can therefore define an order relation $\leq$ on the set $P/\mathord{\cong}$ of equivalence
classes of $P$ modulo the equivalence relation $\cong$. By Proposition 1.3.9, the
set $P/\mathord{\cong}$ is a linear order with the relation $\leq$.

Note, that if $L \prec M$ (that is, $L\preceq M$ but $M \ncong L$), there is a unique
$m \in M$ such that $L$ is isomorphic to the set $\downarrow(m) = \{m′ \in M \mid m′ < m\}$
with the restricted order from $M$.

Therefore, if we denote the $\cong$-equivalence class of $L$ by $[L]$, the set
$$\{\alpha \in P/\mathord{\cong} \mid \alpha < [L]\}$$
is isomorphic to $L$.

Now suppose that $W \subseteq P/\mathord{\cong}$ is a nonempty set of $\cong$-equivalence classes.
Let $\alpha = [L]$ be an arbitrary element of $W$. Consider the set
$$L_W = \{l \in L\mid [\downarrow(l)] \in W\}$$

If $L_W$ is empty, clearly $[L]$ is the least element of $W$. If $L_W$ is nonempty,
then it has (as subset of the well-ordered set $L$) a least element $l_W$. But
then $[\downarrow(l_W)]$ is the least element of $W$. So every nonempty subset of $P/ \mathord{\cong}$
has a least element, and therefore $P/\mathord{\cong}$ is a well-ordered set.

There cannot be an injective function from $P/\mathord{\cong}$ into $X$, for suppose $f$
is such a function. Then $f$ gives a bijective function between $P/\mathord{\cong}$ and a
subset $Y_f$ of $X$; we can then give $Y_f$ the same well-ordering as $P/\mathord{\cong}$, so we
have $(Y_f ,\leq) \cong (P/\mathord{\cong},\leq)$. This is impossible however, since $[(Y_f ,\leq)]$ is an
element of $P/\mathord{\cong}$ (see Proposition 1.3.7).

Lemma 1.3.7 There can be at most one embedding from one well-order $L$
into another well-order $M$. Therefore, if $L$ is a well-ordered set and $l \in L$,
$L$ is never isomorphic to $\{l′ \in L| l′ < l\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true that a well-ordered set cannot be isomorphic to a proper subset of itself, but it is true that it cannot be isomorphic to a proper initial segment of itself.

If $P/\cong$ can be injected into $X$, then there is some equivalence class of $(Y,\leq_Y)$ which is in $P/\cong$ which is isomorphic to $P/\cong$, and this means that we have a well-ordered set which is isomorphic to a proper initial segment of itself. And that is a contradiction. The initial segment is all those elements strictly below the equivalence class of $(Y,\leq_Y)$.

Comment: thanks for point out about the point on Lemma 1.3.7.   OK, so if there's an injection $f:P/\cong \rightarrow X$, then $(P/\cong, \leq) \cong (Y_f,\leq_{Y_f}) \cong [(Z, \leq)] \subset (P/\cong, \leq)$. Here $\leq_{Y_f}$ is induced from the $\leq$ in $(P/\cong, \leq)$, $(Z, \leq)$ is the subset in $(L, \leq)$ corresponding to $(Y_f, \leq_{Y_f})$, and $[(Z, \leq)]$ is the equivalent class of $(Z, \leq)$. But why $[(Z, \leq)]$ is a proper initial segment in $(P/\cong, \leq)$ (hence caused contradiction)?

Comment: Because $(Y,\leq_Y)$ is not strictly smaller than itself.

Comment: I still don't understand your explanation. So I updated the question a bit with my visualization of the proof. Could you please have a look, see if could give me a lead?

Comment: Maybe you should try to understand this with the concrete case of $X$ being $\omega$. In the case $P/\cong$ is just $\omega_1$, and it's a bit easier to understand the arguments when you have a concrete set in your mind for that.

Comment: @assaf-karagila I just spent a few days understanding what is $\omega_1$. Now, I see that the author tried to avoid introducing Ordinal number so that the proof is not so direct. But still, I couldn't understand the last line. With $X$ being $\omega$ and $P/\cong$ being $\omega_1$, $(P/\cong, \leq)$ is actually the ordinal number. but why the ordinal number cannot map to $\omega$?

Comment: @athos: Note that $\omega_1$ is the set of all countable ordinals; and note that if $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal, then there is some $Y\subseteq\omega$ and $\prec_Y$ such that $(Y,\prec_Y)\cong(\alpha,\in)$. Therefore $P/\cong$ is an ordinal which is larger than all the countable ordinals, because every countable ordinal embeds as an initial segment of $P/\cong$.